# PySFML command doesn't work

Tags: python, sfml

I tried to install **pySFML** but I have some problems on start.
I put some code in terminal following [this page](http://www.python-sfml.org/download.html#ubuntu):
    *sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sonkun/sfml-development

    sudo apt-get update

    sudo apt-get install python-sfml*
Later I tried to run any example command but each doesn't works.

sfml-sound # will run the example 'sound'
sfml-shader
sfml-X11
sfml-voip

pysfml-sound # will run the same example but it's actually a python script that uses the binding
pysfml-pong
pysfml-sockets
pysfml-spacial-music
pysfml-pyqt4

**Error is: *"command not found"***
I'm a beginner, what can I do?
Thanks for answers.

Comment: Have each command succeed ? (give us the full shell session in a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)) Seems that the last have not installed the package.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that each command doesn't works.

Comment: Consider installing the package from debian: Python 2: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python-sfml, Python 3: https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python3-sfml

Comment: Which is your OS ?

Comment: While installing the package from debian I needed to install like this *sudo apt-get install **libsfml-audio2.3v5*** instead of *libsfml-audio2* but it looks ok.

Comment: My os: Ubuntu version 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Can you provides the output of each command ?

Comment: Hi again, following commands: **sudo add-apt-repository ppa:sonkun/sfml-development** ->[answer](http://pastebin.com/sqdZy12L),  **sudo apt-get update** ->[answer](http://pastebin.com/x39NWsRi),  **sudo apt-get install python-sfml** ->[answer](http://pastebin.com/8Hu4CpK2). Thanks...

Comment: Now I see some 404 errors -  Not found